# duplicate counts and conditional screening in awk or python

Tags: python, python-2.7, awk

I have a dataset as below:

```
a  b  2.7
a  b  9.4
a  b  6.9
x  l  0.004
y  m  0.5
```

indicate hoe many duplicates

I need to get the duplicates out in column 2 and collapse but also get the lowest value in 3rd column for the duplicates. If no duplicates seen, then print as is. Also 
if col 2 is same print lowest col 3 
ouput hoping for :

```
3 a b 2.7
1 x  l  0.004
1 y  m  0.5
```

I have so far sorted to get the counts of duplicates( as shown in col1). However I cannot proceed further to get the lowest 3col value.I would like to accomplish this in awk or python. Please help !

```
sort -k2,2nr myfile.txt| less
```

geneart.

Comment: What if one of the inputs is `c b 1`?

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
summary = {}

# ** If order is important, use collections.OrderedDcit **
#
#import collections
#summary = collections.OrderedDict()

with open('dataset.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        col1, col2, value = line.split()
        value = float(value)
        if col2 not in summary:
            summary[col2] = [0, col1, value] # count, col1, col3
        else:
            if value < summary[col2][1]:
                summary[col2][1] = col1
                summary[col2][2] = value
        summary[col2][0] += 1

for col2, s in summary.iteritems():
    print '{0[0]} {0[1]} {1} {0[2]}'.format(s, col2)
```

---

In awk:

```
awk '{if (!($2 in min) || $3<min[$2]) {min[$2]=$3; col1[$2]=$1} cnt[$2]++} \
     END{for (i in cnt) print cnt[i]" "col1[i]" "i" "min[i]}' dataset.txt
```

Comment: What if one of the inputs is `c b 1`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, This code output col1 of the smallest value: `* c b 1.0` instead of `* a b 2.7`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this

```
with open("Input.txt") as inFile:
    lines = [line.split() for line in inFile]
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
getCol2 = itemgetter(1)
for col2, grp in groupby(sorted(lines, key = getCol2), getCol2):
    grp = list(grp)
    res = [len(grp)] + min(grp, key = getCol2)
    print " ".join(map(str, res))
```

**Output**

```
3 a b 2.7
1 x l 0.004
1 y m 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

By Gawk

awk --version|head -1

GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 4.3.2)

```
awk '{str=$1 FS $2;if (!(str in min) || $3<min[str]) min[str]=$3;sum[str]++} 
    END {for (i in sum) print sum[i],i,min[i]}' myfile.txt
```